# Корректная работа 2 javascrip'тов

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Есть два скрипта. Один скрипт загрузки uploadifive,а второй скрипт добавления комментария! как можно сделать что бы они оба выполнялись при нажатии на кнопку отправления ?(ниже представлен код кнопки и код обеих скриптов в отдельности)

```
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Отправить" />
```

Скрипт загрузчика uploadifive

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
                'auto'         : false,
                'formData'     : {'test' : 'something'},
                'queueID'      : 'queue',
                'uploadScript' : 'insnt.php',

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Скрипт добавления комментария

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
      msg = $('.input').val(); 
      if (msg.length > 100) 
      {
        alert("Characters must be only 10000");
      }else if (msg == ""){
        alert("Please enter a message");
      }else{
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true); 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/insnt.php",
          data: "msg=" + msg,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $('#addcomment').after(html);
            $('#listdiv .list:last').hide().slideDown('slow'); 
            $('.input').val("");
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать метод [upload](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/upload-2/) под событием **submit** на добавление комментария. А вообще, читая [официальную документацию](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), можно найти много интересного ;)

**UPD**

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'         : false,
        'formData'     : {'test' : 'something'},
        'queueID'      : 'queue',
        'uploadScript' : 'insnt.php',
    });
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
        // дальше весь ваш код по добавлению комментария
    });
});
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете как то скрестить submit и upload ?

Comment: Я не селекционер и о скрещевании не так много знаю, но вызывать метод действительно предлагаю из-под submit. Если не получится таким образом, то можно повесить вызов метода, как в примере выше, на кнопку, по нажатию на которую, вы добавляете коммент (*кнопка id="addcomment"*)

Comment: Вот как я попробовал поставить, скажите что может быть не правильным ?
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
 $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'         : false,
    'formData'     : {'test' : 'something'},
    'queueID'      : 'queue',
    'uploadScript' : 'insertcomment.php',

 });
 </script>

Comment: @OverLoader, код **uploadifive** вынесите за пределы **submit** и выше него, а внутри пропишите только:

    $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');

Comment: Спасибо!Вы имеете ввиду что то на подобие такого ?
 <script> $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'         : false,
    'formData'     : {'test' :                    'something'},
    'queueID'      : 'queue',
    'uploadScript' : 'insertcomment.php',

   });$('#addcomment').submit(function() { 
$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');      
 });
    </script>

Comment: @OverLoader, дополнил в ответе